# How to load instance variable on ajax success request after page load in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method in api that returns json object of vehicles.

```
class TestApi
 def test_method
  @vehicle = Vehicle.where(owner_id: current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: @vehicle }
  end
 end
end
```

I have a view page from where I do the get request to test_method to get the @vehicle object. How can I keep changing @vehicle object using ajax on success and populate in my view so that on different user view I get the dynamic @vehicle object?

```
.container
  - @vehicle.each do |v|
   %p v.name

:js
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/v1/vehicle/test_method" + rv_id,
      success: function(result){
        console.log('Got the result', html);
      }
    })
  })
```